# How to create SVN repository on server?

Tags: svn, webserver

How to create SVN repository on server? Although i have found various articles on this but still facing issues while creating repository on my website. Right now i am using [assembla](http://www.assembla.com) as my SVN repository, but want to create my own on my hosting.

Comment: What issues? This question is very vague and basically impossible to answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

1. **Create a Repository:**

   `svnadmin create /svnrepos`
2. **Create a SVN User**

   `vi /svnrepos/conf/svnserve.conf`

   > anon-access = none
   >
   > auth-access = write
   >
   > password-db = passwd

   **And add users in the format:** `user = password`

   E.g.: `tony = mypassword`
3. **Import Your Project**

   (Assuming you’ve put your project files in `/projects/myrailsproject`)

   `svn import /projects/myrailsproject file:///svnrepos/myrailsproject`
4. **Start the SVN Server as Daemon**

   `svnserve -d`

   **Done!** You should now have an Apache Subversion server running with one project named myrailsproject.

   Try checking it out of the repository:

   `svn co svn://192.168.0.2/svnrepos/myyrailsproject`

   Since we set anon-access to none you should be prompted for username and password which you created in the file `/svnrepos/conf/passwd`.

Comment: For password vi /svnrepos/conf/passwd

Comment: Reference link http://www.civicactions.com/blog/2010/may/25/how_set_svn_repository_7_simple_steps

Comment: svnadmin create does not seem to initialize the repo with branches, tags, or trunk sub-directories. How is this done?

Comment: You have to mkdir those directories. Someone working alone might be happy with just trunk. So in the directory you are working you mkdir trunk, then svn add trunk

Comment: It supposes i need copy my project to server to import. Is it possible just export project from my local folder in remote repository?