# Where can I find a fake svn repository?

Tags: svn, git-svn

I am following the git-svn tutorial: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-as-a-Client.

To practice, the tutorial suggests creating a local svn repository.

> svnsync init file:///tmp/test-svn http://progit-example.googlecode.com/svn/

Unfortunately the svn repo is no longer available.
This sounds really stupid but ... where could I find a dumb svn repository (with a trunk/branches/tags layout) that already has a few commits?

Thanks !

Comment: Create one on your own?

Comment: I am currently doing it.
But a dumb skeleton with a few commits would have been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

That was followed by [progit/progit2 issue 631](https://github.com/progit/progit2/issues/631), and the conclusion was similar to the comments:

> The original SVN test repository is gone.
>   The reader have to use another SVN test repository.

Creating one's own SVN repository ([as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11810992/6309)) remains the quickest way to follow that tutorial.